# How to send data to Service Bus Topic with Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a default C# based HTTP Trigger here and I wish to send data "Hello Name" to Service Bus Topic (already created). I'm coding in Azure Portal.

How to do it Service Bus output binding?

This is not working. Any help available?

- Reference missing for handling Service Bus?
- How to define Connection of service bus? Where is `Functions.json`
- How to send a message to service bus?

```
//This FunctionApp get triggered by HTTP and sends message to Azure Service Bus

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Company.Function
{
    public static class HttpTriggerCSharp1
    {
        [FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp1")]
        [return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] // I added this for SB Output. Where to define.

        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)

        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string name = req.Query["name"];
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;
            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
            // I added this for SB Output
            return responseMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this example. It is much clearer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/service-bus#using-icollector-with-service-bus-queue-bindings
You define the connectionstring in the application settings, in a setting called `ServiceBusConnection`

Comment: I copied sample and "return: ServiceBus" cause error: "The type or namespace name 'ServiceBusAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [FunctionsHttpTriggerCodeNet]csharp(CS0246)
The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [FunctionsHttpTriggerCodeNet]csharp(CS0246)"

Comment: See in my samples collection. There is a queue-triggered function, but the mechanism is the same with the output. There is also a sample local.settings.json which has the connection string https://github.com/sebader/azure-samples-collection/tree/master/AzureFunctions/SampleFunctions

Comment: Where do you define "Connection = "queueconstring" in your code? Is it direct copy and paste from Azure portal?

Comment: please take a look at the files in the sample repo I linked above, in the local.settings.json (that file is for local debugging)

Comment: I'm getting namespace error for "[return: ServiceBus" and "Connection". Am I missing assembly reference or directive?

Comment: I'm sorry, if you don't take my advise and take a look at the samples I provided you above and start from there, I can't help you. I suggest you clone my sample repo and start there.

Comment: Thanks and I do appreciate your help. I have looked your sample and added "Connection = "queueconstring" to local.settings.json, but I'm getting error with "ServiceBus" and "Connection" of [return: ServiceBus("queue1", Connection = "queueconstring")]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two bindings to send data to service bus. First is what you show, using the `return` binding, after installing two packages `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` and `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`, then you will be able to send data. And you could not do it cause your function type is `IActionResult` and you are trying to return a `string` datatype (responseMessage).

So if you want to send the whole `responseMessage`, just `return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);`, it will work. And the result would be like below image.

[image]

And if you want to use `return responseMessage;` you should change your method type to `string`, it will be `public static async Task<string> RunAsync` and result will be below.

[image]

Another binding you could refer to below code or this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/service-bus#azure-service-bus-output-binding).

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
[return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
public static async Task RunAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] MessageSender messagesQueue,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        string name = req.Query["name"];
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
        : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseMessage);
    Message m1 = new Message(bytes);
    await messagesQueue.SendAsync(m1);
    
}
```

> How to define Connection of service bus? Where is Functions.json

In the local you should define the connection in the `local.settings.jon`, you could use any name with the connection, then in the binding `Connection` value should be the name you set in the JSON file. And because you are using **C#**, you could not modify the `function.json` file - there will be a `function.json` file in the debug folder. You could only change the binding in the code.

Hope this could help you, if you still have other problem , please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I have run in terminal of VS Code: PS C:\Azure\azure-sandbox\FunctionsHttpTriggerCodeNet> Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus -Version 4.1.1
Install-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Version'.

Comment: So I'm currently stuck on not having  directive or assembly reference for Service Bus on VS Code(C#)

Comment: I solved with dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 4.1.1

Comment: @Kenny_I, So you have already solved this problem, if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you first install [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/4.1.1?_src=template) NuGet package. Then make sure you are using it in your project:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus;
```

Make sure you clean and build the project to make sure you have no errors.

Then you need to make sure you have a `"ServiceBusConnection"` connection string inside your `local.settings.json` file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ServiceBusConnection": "Endpoint=sb://...",
  }
}
```

Which you can get if you go to **Azure portal -> Service bus namespace -> Shared access policies -> RootManageSharedAccessKey -> Primary Connection String**. Copy and paste this connection string inside `"ServiceBusConnection"`. You can also use the **Secondary Connection String** as well.

**Note:** Service bus queues/topics have shared access policies as well. So if you don't want to use the Service bus namespace level access policies, you can create one at queue/topic level, so you your function app only has access to the queue/topic defined in your namespace.

Also if you decide to publish your function app, you will need to make sure you create a configuration application setting for `"ServiceBusConnection"`, since `local.settings.json` is only used for local testing.

Comment: Hello , I followed the above steps and it works fine in my local dev environment. Once I publish to the azure function via VS. The request to send message to the function returns a success but the message is not added to the Service bus. 
Any thoughts what might be causing this issue ?