# Azure function not sending message to Service Bus Topic

Tags: c#, azure, service, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I created a function app which is triggered via Http. The function app should publish a message to Azure Service Bus Topic. But, for some reason, message is not getting published into service bus topic. Function app is triggered successfully and I'm able to post the message from Postman and receive success 200 OK response, there are no errors whatsoever. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Extensions
{
    public class HttpInputServiceBusOutput
    {
        [FunctionName("MessageProcessorFunction")]
        [return: ServiceBus("myTopic", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
            public async Task<string> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "sms")] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
            {
                log.LogInformation("HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

                return "hello World";
            }
    }
}
```

**Local.Settings.Json File**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "ServiceBusConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://DDXXXXXXXXXX.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=ghg...................",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

Please note that I'm using .Net core 3.1 Version framework. As such , I have installed `Microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.servicebus` version 5.3.0 instead of `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus` as per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#differences-with-net-class-library-functions).

[image]

Comment: Seems its already answered or you can use this reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607880/how-to-send-data-to-service-bus-topic-with-azure-functions

Comment: Thank you everyone for the reply, I found the answer, Issue was the filter in subscription. We have removed all the filters in a topic subscription. We then realized that a subscription should have at least any one filter to accept any message. Thus, we were able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end we found after changing `Route` to null, we could able to receive the messages in the service bus. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp21
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        [return: ServiceBus("myqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        public static async Task<string> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, 
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Swetha, Issue is now resolved. :)